# MPEG-4 (Base Media / Version 2) to MPEG-4 (3GPP Media Release 5)

Tags: conversion, 3gp, video-codecs, mpeg4

Hi I want to convert an MP4 file to work with a [Sony Ericsson Aino](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_aino-2810.php)

Here is a detailed comparison of the file format that I want to `convert to` which is *MP4(3GPP)* and the file that I want to `convert from` which is *MP4(BaseMedia)*. I am not an expert when it comes to codec details, video containers and file formats.

[Detailed Comparison](https://superuser.com/#deadlink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look online and it seems the Aino likes Mpeg-4 Simple profile video at around 0.5mbit/sec at a resolution of 320x240.

I'd suggest downloading and installing Handbrake:
http://handbrake.fr/

Select a file for input and customise the iPod Legacy preset to the following settings:

Container: MP4 file
Untick the three boxes.

Picture: Width 320, Height 240
Video Filters: None
Video: Video Codec Mpeg-4, Average Bitrate 500kbps
Audio: Audio Codec AAC, Mixdown Mono, Bitrate 32kbps

It may well work out for you, let me know if it doesn't and I'll try to suggest more things you can do.

Comment: Hi ruairi I will try this when I get a hold of the unit again as its not mine. I believe you can still help me by that time. Thanks!

Comment: Best of luck! :)

Comment: hi I have a question i tried mp4 container and output file is m4v could it be mp4? and for the audio it was too slow with very low pitch. source file is a VOB

Comment: In Handbrake under the audio tab there is a DRC (Dynamic Range Compression) option, experiment with this. DRC will increase the volume on quieter audio parts, and loud parts will remain the same volume. When you say the pitch is incorrect, how bad is it? Is it twice as slow, or maybe just a few percent? Does the video lose synchronisation? Also try renaming m4v to mp4 - some players will play either.

Comment: thanks, I did it

DESTINATION:
Change Extenstion to MP4

CONTAINER 
MP4 file Uncheck the three boxes.

PICTURE
Width 320 x Height 240 
Uncheck Keep Aspect Ratio
AnamorphiC Custom 
Modulus 16
PAR Width 320
PAR Height 240

VIDEOFILTERS 
None 

VIDEO
Video Codec Mpeg-4, 
FPS 25, 
Average Bitrate 1200kbps 

AUDIO:
Audio Codec AAC
Mixdown Mono
Bitrate 64kbps
Samplerate 32
DRC 1.6.
This is abit off topic but what tool do I need to merge VOB files chapters can handbrake do that?

Comment: I checked iPod5G Support to encode with H.264 Baseline Profile 3.0 which is used by aino.